# Pages of my webpage positioned on each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, css-position

I am creating a website where the homepage has an automatic image slider, I have this issue where the other pages (service page) overlap and stay right on the home page. I tried fixing this issue setting the homepage to 100vh and the image from the service stays right on top.

I tried removing the absolute positioning on the slider and desc and that disfigured the outlook. I tried forcing the code to work by creating a dummy div and setting a height to push down the service page div and it kinda worked but I want my code as clean as possible, I know someone has a better to deal with this please help out.

I also want the images to be positioned next to each as inline and that is not working.

The three pictures you see on the automatic slider are a separate page and I am trying to set to it below the home page (automatic image slider)

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var slideLength = slides.length;

  // Fade in the slide
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(slideIndex == slideLength) {
      slideIndex = 0;
    }
    slides[slideIndex].classList.add("fadeIn");
  }, 10);

  //Fade out the SLide
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(slideIndex == slideLength) {
      slideIndex = 0;
    }
    slides[slideIndex].classList.remove("fadeIn");
  }, 3980);

  slideIndex++;
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
}
```

```css
.desc-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 23%;
}

.desc {
  margin: auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.mySlides {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity: 0;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------
@Home page
-----------------------------------------------------*/
.main{
  width:calc(100%- 300px);
}

.homePage {
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.slideshow-container {
  margin: auto;
}

.fadeIn {
  opacity:1;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------
@Service Page
-----------------------------------------------------*/
div .services {
  width:100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding:10px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.row {

}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section id="homePage">
    <div class="homePage">
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="Images/eventbg1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="desc-container">
            <div class="desc p30 whitebg">
              <h6 class="greytxt">Luxury Events</h6>
              <h1 class="blacktxt">WE CREATE BEAUTIFUL EVENTS</h1>
              <p class="greytxt">Join us for a “No Question too Small, Large or Outrageous” Chat about All things Bridal! This is your chance to have two industry experts answer your queries on any topic that is keeping you up at night.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="Images/restaurantbg1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="desc-container">
            <div class="desc p30 whitebg">
              <h6 class="greytxt">Creating Impact</h6>
              <h1 class="blacktxt"> STRATEGY AND SALES</h1>
              <p class="greytxt"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="Images/memorialbg1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="desc-container">
            <div class="desc p30 whitebg">
              <h6 class="greytxt">Lasting Memories</h6>
              <h1 class="blacktxt">SERVING WITH LOVE</h1>
              <p class="greytxt"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="services">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="Images/eventbg2.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="Images/restaurantbg2.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="Images/memorialbg2.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: If the site is live and you're able to share it, your odds a solution will probably go up 10 fold.

Comment: @Slbox I have added a live link. Please view and see if you could help . Thank you

Comment: as far as i know there's no neat/clean way to get the height from an absolute positioned element to a relatively positioned parent, they tend to be a bit hacky. I've seen a fair share of responsive sliders use JS to get the height and then inline inject it to the slide container, it would be the most accurate result without changing what you have... or you could set those images to background images and force a height like 100vh on everything.

Comment: Thanks @Jasmine. Was wondering. I actually created a dummy div with a height and it forced the other down. Thank you I await other comments - if any one has another idea on how to go about it. Thank once again Jas